# rendering tex: sqrt: placement of root

Tags: tex-core, sqrt

EDIT: after reading egreg's comment, changing from \sqrt[3]{x} to \root 3 \of{x}, to indicate using plain TeX, not LaTeX

Consider `$$\sqrt{x}$$` vs `$$\root 3 \of{x}$$`.

The latter has a 'root' of 3.

How do we typeset this?

On page 443 of the TeX Book, rule 11, it describes typesetting the radical atom: `\radcal` and `\sqrt`. However, it only describes "root-less" types, like `\sqrt{x}`, and not the ones with a root, like `\root 3 \of{x}`

Question: how is the root/3 in a sqrt typeset?

Comment: In plain TeX (as opposed to LaTeX) it is `\root 3\of{x}`. The TeXbook, page 130 (bottom). Do you mean you want a description of how LaTeX implements `\sqrt[3]{x}`?

Comment: @egreg: thanks for clarification, changed to \root 3 of{x} . (source of confusion: reading TeX book, but used LaTeX most of my life)

Comment: @egreg : so I'm reading the bottom of page 130. It's describing how I can use \root -- but how do I implement \root ? (I'm writing a WYSIWYG math equation editor -- and I'm trying to figure out how TeX renders roots)

Comment: The description of the macro is on page 360, starting from `\newbox\rootbox`.

Comment: @egreg: 
\newbox\rootbox
\def\root#1\of{\setbox\rootbox=
  \hbox{$\m@th \scriptscriptstyle{#1}$}\mathpalette\r@@t}
\def\r@@t#1#2{\setbox0=\hbox{$\m@th #1\sqrt{#2}$}
  \dimen@=\ht0 \advance\dimen@ by-\dp0
  \mkern5mu \raise.6\dimen@\copy\rootbox \mkern-10mu \box0} . ... fascinating, wasn't aware the TeX macro system was this "powerful"